# point color in ggbetweenstats

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to change the point color in ggbetweenstats?
I have checked the document and didn't see a parameter that can simpliy change the point color. 
I try the ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c(purple,darkred,blue)) but nothing happened.

There three colors has been identified and the detailed code is as following:

```
ggbetweenstats(
  data = box.dat, 
  x = Class, 
  y = Pre_NeoAts,
  notch = T,
  outlier.tagging = F,
  messages = FALSE,
  mean.color = "black",
  mean.size = 3
)   +   ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c(purple,darkred,blue))
```

Could anyone give me a hint?
Many thanks advanced!

Comment: If you want more flexibility, use `ggplot2` directly instead of through `ggbetweenstats`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the color point of the mean?

You can change it with the argument `mean.color` in `ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats()`.
However you can only assign a single color here.

In addition, each group is already assigned a color as shown in the example below:

```r
library(gapminder)

ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
    data = dplyr::filter(.data = gapminder, year == 2007),
    x = continent,
    y = lifeExp,
    messages = FALSE
)
```

[image]

Thus, there is already a `scale_color_discrete()` defined in this plot. So if you add a `scale_color_*()` function it will replace this scale. It does not seem possible to get different colors.

Comment: Yes thank you so much. By adding + scale_color_manual(values=c(purple,darkred,blue)), I can change the color manually!

Comment: I don't know how this is the answer to the question asked. You are not showing how to change the point colors, which is what was asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can change the point colors. 
(This is with `ggstatsplot 0.0.6`, which is currently on `CRAN`)

```r
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  messages = FALSE,
  mean.color = 'black'
) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

[image]

Moreover, you can also specify `palette` from your `package` of choosing to change colors instead of specifying them manually:

```r
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  messages = FALSE,
  palette = "Royal1",
  package = "wesanderson"
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>